# display / reading 8 bit grayscale (uncompressed) TIFF in picturebox and doing manipulation with AForge.net c#

Tags: c#, aforge

I have a grayscale TIFF raw image.
I would like to display it in picturebox and then do some manipulation with AForge.Net.
I wonder what is the best practice for this.
I could not display the image - I either get black "picturebox"
getting error "outofmemory" when trying to convert to grayscale.
getting error unsupported format in AForge
and more..
any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here
An article on how to use GDI+ methods for displaying 16-bit raw images
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31581/Displaying-bit-Images-Using-C

Comment: I have tried this and it didnt work for me, running this program - the output is displayed as black

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here
[C# - Converting 8-bit or 16-bit grayscale raw pixel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832948/c-sharp-converting-8-bit-or-16-bit-grayscale-raw-pixel-data)

It gives you an  example code for converting the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for trying, but I need 8-bit, I have seen this also but could not understand how to do it for 8-bits